# concatenate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to create a multi-input CNN using three imported networks. However i don't fully understand the error below. Shouldn't the keras functional api recognize the input layers in the imported networks ?

```
import tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet152, InceptionV3, InceptionResNetV2
```

Importing 1 of the models:

```
resnet152 = ResNet152(
weights='imagenet',
include_top=False,
input_shape=((224, 224, 3))
)

for layer in resnet152.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

Merging the inputs and outputs of the 3 models.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model

resnet152_copy = Model(inputs=resnet152.input, outputs=resnet152.output)
inceptionV3_copy = Model(inputs=inceptionV3.input, outputs=inceptionV3.output)
inception_resnet152_copy = Model(inputs=inceptionV3_resnet152.input, outputs=inceptionV3_resnet152.output)


concat_feature_layer = layers.concatenate(axis=4)([resnet152_copy, inceptionV3_copy, inception_resnet152_copy])
fully_connected_dense_big = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(concat_feature_layer)
dropout_one = layers.Dropout(0.5)(fully_connected_dense_big)
flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()(dropout_one)
fully_connected_dense_small = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dropout_two = layers.Dropout(0.5)(fully_connected_dense_small)
fully_connected_dense_class = layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')

model = Model(
    inputs=[resnet152.input, inceptionV3.input, inceptionV3_resnet152.input],
    outputs=fully_connected_dense_class
)
```

i keep getting the following error in concat layer:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7cef36b1c56e> in <module>
      6 
      7 
----> 8 concat_feature_layer = layers.concatenate(axis=4)([resnet152_copy, inceptionV3_copy, inception_resnet152_copy])
      9 fully_connected_dense_big = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(concat_feature_layer)
     10 dropout_one = layers.Dropout(0.5)(fully_connected_dense_big)

TypeError: concatenate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

Comment: Please post the full error message. I guess it appeared in line 8, but I am not sure. And please post the full code of a minimum example. In your code snippet, name `layers` is undefined.

Comment: In `layers.concatenate(axis=4)([resnet152_copy, inceptionV3_copy, inception_resnet152_copy])` you close parentheses and then reopen them - that's what you would do if `layers.concatenate(axis=4)` returned a function you would then call, but that's not what you're doing - you probably just wanted to continue passing arguments and should have added the other parameters separated by commas?

Comment: @Grismar.  No, he's calling it the way the documentation says to.

Comment: hi grismar you are right and wrong... i the documentation it says so, however i keep on getting the same error. I have tried to specify that it's the model.outputs in the concat layer. If i only pass the network without .outputs it says nonetype object is not subscriptable...

Comment: concatenate and Concatenate are not the same thing. You are probably confusing the two.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://keras.io/ko/layers/merge/) for the difference between `Concatenate` and `concatenate`. Example usage can be found [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/) and [here](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#manipulate-complex-graph-topologies), respectively.

Comment: Please do not unnecessarily clutter your code with irrelevant imports and a whole *bunch* of `print` statements which are completely useless for possible respondents, since you do not provide their output (edited out); code here is supposed to be *minimal*, i.e. the minimum required to describe/reproduce the issue.

Comment: Isn't concatenate just an interface for Concatenate? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55050/what-is-the-difference-between-concatenate-and-concatenate-layers-in-keras

Comment: I think i need to somehow change the size of the output tensor from the resnet152. The other networks outputs different shapes... I am trying to recreate this network and they concat the three CNN's into a feature vector. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fneur.2020.00375/full

Comment: @FrankYellin and NiklasMunkholmHjort, thanks for your reponses - I see what you mean, but will leave my comment in case someone comes to the same (erroneous) conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two forms of concatenation layers in `tf.keras`:

- You have the [functional form `tf.keras.layers.concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate), which should be called as

```
concat_feature_layer = layers.concatenate([resnet152_copy, inceptionV3_copy, inception_resnet152_copy], axis=4)
```

- Then you have the [layer object `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate) which should be called first to instantiate the object before operating on the inputs:

```
concat_feature_layer = layers.Concatenate(axis=4)([resnet152_copy, inceptionV3_copy, inception_resnet152_copy])
```

Comment: I think my problem is that resnet output shape is (None, 7, 7, 2048) while the incep networks has (None, 8, 8, 1536). I have tried the first solution since i am using the functional api. The code above gives = TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: @NiklasMunkholmHjort If those are the shapes, then neither concatenation will solve it... You first need to decide how to you want to make the other dimensions of the same size.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers guys. on a final note would this be the right aproach to solve this by changing the shape of the output tensor only for resnet or can this lead to bad filtering ? resnet152 = ResNet152(
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False,
    input_shape=((224, 224, 3))
)

for layer in resnet152.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

reshaping = layers.Reshape((8, 8, 1568))(resnet152.output)
re_config_resnet152 = tensorflow.keras.Model(inputs=resnet152.input, outputs=reshaping)

Comment: I haven't used the "ResNet" model directly, so I can't comment of the invocation. What I can tell you is that is not a matter of reshaping. The number of values happens to match in this case (to my surprise), but the 2nd and 3rd tensor dimension have spatial information, so I wouldn't mix it. You should either pad the output of the resnet or trim the output of the inception network so that they match.